# Cannot get rid of nuget warning NU5128 about missing dependency group

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

[Env: nuget.exe 5.9.1.11, VS Pro 2019 16.9.6, W10 x64 1909]

I am having trouble configuring the `dependencies` section of my `.nuspec` file so nuget generates a package which correctly contains the Dependency for .NET Framework 4.7.2. I consistently get the warning

```
WARNING: NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the
lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
- Add a dependency group for .NETFramework4.7.2 to the nuspec
```

when I run the `nuget pack` command. In the .nupkg archive, there are `lib\net472\MyLib.dll` and `lib\net472\MyLib.xml` files generated by nuget. (I am running `nuget` in the VS project directory which contains a `.csproj` file and my `.nuspec` file.) Here are the different configurations of the `dependencies` section that I have tried (my library does have a dependency on the MathNet.Numerics NuGet package):

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2" />
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2" />
    <group>
        <dependency id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.15.0" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group>
        <dependency id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.15.0" />
    </group>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2" />
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group>
        <dependency id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.15.0" />
    </group>
    <group targetFramework="net472" />
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework="net472" />
    <group>
        <dependency id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.15.0" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework="net472" />
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework="net472">
        <dependency id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.15.0" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

&

```
<dependencies>
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2">
        <dependency id="MathNet.Numerics" version="4.15.0" />
    </group>
</dependencies>
```

& no `<dependencies></dependencies>` section as well.

Comment: It seems to be a problem about nuget.exe: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8713

Answer (score 0):

I used NuGet Version: 6.5.0.154,
put

```
    <dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.1" />
    </dependencies>
```

under metadata element as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element

and the warning did not show up.
Hope it helped.